# Exception when trying to delete a service on remote vm

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and scripting and am stuck with a weird situation.

I'm trying to create a script that will delete a running service and install a new service (also copying files and etc...).

The issue is the command to delete the service when I run the command separately from my script the command works.
When I run my command as part of the script I get an exception :

> :Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s): "The remote
>   procedure call failed and did not execute. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x800706BF)"

This was i run separately :

```
Connect-VIServer -Server "IP" -Protocol https -User "User" -Password "Password"


$password = "Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "User"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)


(gwmi win32_service -ComputerName "IP" -Credential $credential -filter "name='Service Name'").delete()
```

The Script i run when it fails :

```
Connect-VIServer -Server IP -Protocol https -User "User" -Password "Password"

$Template = Get-Template -Name "Template Name"

Set-Template $Template -ToVM

$VM = Get-VM -Name "Template Name"

Start-VM $VM

Start-Sleep -s 100


#Creating PScredentials
$password = "Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "User"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)

#Creating a New folder on vm
$Create_New_Folder =
{ 
New-Item -Path "Host Path" -ItemType directory
}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "PC IP" -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock $Create_New_Folder

#Copy File From Localhost To vm
Get-Item "Host Folder" | Copy-VMGuestFile -Destination "VM LOcal Path" -VM "Template Name" -LocalToGuest -GuestUser "User" -GuestPassword "Password" -Force -Verbose


#Deleting a service on remote vm
(gwmi win32_service -ComputerName "IP" -Credential $credential -filter "name='Service Name'").delete()

#Retart VM so the service will be removed
Restart-VM "Template Name" -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Is there a difference between ComputerName "PC IP" and ComputerName "IP"?

Comment: Those are just names i changed in order to upload it to here... in the script its the same ip.

Comment: Have you tried to put it into a script block like with create new Folder?

Comment: No... i saw it works fine without using it in a script block... but i will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how `gwmi`performs remoting. If it uses DCOM or something else you might need additional permissions.  You can try to use `Invoke-Command` to delete to service (-> you're already using it to create a new folder). Example:

```
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName "PC IP" -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
      (gwmi win32_service -filter "name='Service Name'").delete()
  }
```

By using `Invoke-Command` you're using a more "standardized" remoting mechanism.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, as Nikolaus and you suggested. It works thanks :)